# Why does <signal.h> prevent the use of "si_" as prefix for the name of some variables?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have been debugging a strange compilation error that I was getting inside my code, and I ended up finding out that I cannot use the prefix `si_` for some variable names (of any type) if `<signal.h>` is included.

Here is a very simple source code example that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <signal.h>

int main(void)
{
    int si_value = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile this with the GNU C Compiler `gcc`, I get the following error:

```
> gcc example.c
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:57:0,
                 from example.c:2:
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:6:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
     int si_value = 0;
         ^
example.c:6:9: error: expected expression before ‘.’ token
```

Nonetheless, if I use another name such as `si_value2`, the error doesn't show up. As a reference, I'm using GCC v7.3.0 on Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 LTS. The same problem is observed with `g++`.

I suppose that this behaviour is due to some macro definition inside the `<signal.h>` header, but after going through it briefly, I couldn't seem to find anything really related.

I honestly can fix it by just using another name. However, my concern is: **how could I elegantly avoid this type of issue in the future?**

---

**Update:** As @F.X. has suggested, using `gcc -E example.c` shows that the variable name is expanded (hence, the error):

```
...
    int 
# 6 "example.c" 3 4
       _sifields._rt.si_sigval 
# 6 "example.c"
                = 0;
...
```

Comment: Can you look at the output of `gcc -E` (right after preprocessor)? It might give you a hint as to what goes wrong.

Comment: Is it just the name `si_value`? Smells like a macro is getting substituted into your code. What about something like `si_vy1ghad563nvy43wd`?

Comment: it's not possible that `si_` prefix is interpreted. `si_value`, that's another story.

Comment: It is time to use some IDE which immediately highlights `si_value` as a macro and allows to jump to definition point...

Comment: @alterigel sorry, `si_vy1ghad563nvy43wd` is also a reserved keyword.

Comment: I forgot to mention that using other names with the `si` prefix work, for some reason. For instance, `si_addr` also reproduces the error, but as @alterigel has pointed out, `si_addr2` or even `si_value2` doesn't.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre *sorry, `si_vy1ghad563nvy43wd` is also a reserved keyword*  Where is that a reserved keyword?  If it exists, I can't find that in POSIX nor the C standard.  Offhand, I don't even see how `si_value` fits into the POSIX "functions and external identifiers" reservation of identifiers.

Comment: so the title of your question is misleading. It's like saying that using variable names starting with `i` doesn't work when you only tried `int`

Comment: @AndrewHenle okay this was a joke.

Comment: @F.X. Thank you very much for the suggestion! I actually get `_sifields._rt.si_sigval` where my `si_value` variable should be. That explains the `expected expression before ‘.’ token` error.

Comment: [#define si_value        _sifields._rt.si_sigval](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/types/siginfo_t.h.html#135)

Comment: Good catch, @MarkPlotnick!

Comment: When you see an error in C that doesn't make sense, there's a macro hidden somewhere :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`<signal.h>` doesn't actually prevent using `si_` as a prefix on your variables. However, the POSIX specification states that this prefix is reserved, in order to allow the header and the library functions that it declares to use these names, without having to worry that they'll conflict with your own variables.

So what's happening here is that `si_value` is defined in some way in the header file, perhaps as a macro or typedef, and your attempt to use the same name conflicts with this. If you used `si_vy1ghad563nvy43wd` it probably would work, but theoretically the header could use that name (thinking that it would be unlikely to conflict with anything an application programmer would use).

C doesn't have real namespaces, so naming conventions like this are used as a simple substitute.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, this answer is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Aren't identifiers starting with '__' reserved for the implementation? Can't it use that instead? Or is that something else?

Comment: I think this is actually a POSIX thing, while `__` is a C thing. So POSIX is trying to avoid names that are reserved to the C implementation.

Comment: But isn't `signal.h` a standard header?

Comment: It may also be a backward compatibility issue -- `signal.h` had already been using lots of `si_` names. Rather than list all these existing names as reserved, it just made the whole prefix reserved.

Comment: C11 reserves names starting `SIG` followed by a capital letter, or `SIG_` followed by a capital letter (C11 [§7.14 Signal handling `<signal.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14p4)). POSIX reserves a lot more symbol prefixes when `<signal.h>` is included — [§2.2.2 The Name Space](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02). The C standard reserves leading `__` for use by the implementation (C11 [§7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3)). Read and take care to avoid conflicts. Or fix 'em when they arise.

Comment: @Kevin: The `<signal.h>` header is both a standard C header and a standard POSIX header.  Since you didn't specify `-std=c11` or similar when you invoked GCC, it enabled all the GNU extensions, which includes the POSIX functions and symbols.  If you specified `-std=c11`, you might need to write `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` on the compiler command line, or a similar `#define` in a header or your code (I recommend doing it in a header, having used it in code once upon a decade ago, and having spent a fair amount of time undoing it since then).

Comment: I never ran GCC for this :). Just curious and asking questions that have now been answered. +1'd the answer.

Comment: I am still not sure if the Linux header is compliant! The `si_value` is not reserved as a macro as such. There's a *separate* list of macro prefixes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: GCC *always* enables not just POSIX, but full `_GNU_SOURCE` extensions, when compiling C++. This is a known bug that's a major pain for them to fix...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: In 'The Name Space' section (previously linked), POSIX says: _Applications shall not declare or define identifiers with the same name as an identifier reserved in the same context. Since macro names are replaced whenever found, independent of scope and name space, macro names matching any of the reserved identifier names shall not be defined by an application if any associated header is included._  Since `si_value` uses one of the reserved prefixes (`si_`), the header is allowed (by POSIX) to define a macro for `si_value`.  Does that explain enough?

Answer (score 12):

> how could I elegantly avoid this type of issues in the future?

You check some [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) for the headers you are using and avoid the names that are documented as reserved.

Comment: Where does it say that `si_value` is a reserved name? All I see is references to a field of that name in the `siginfo_t` structure, but that's not at all the same thing?

Comment: @unwind, the prefix `si_` is reserved when using `<signal.h>`

Comment: @unwind  2.2.2 The namespace

Comment: how can a _prefix_ be reserved?

Comment: @RSahu Ah, okay. That was extremely hard to figure out from that page. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Probably in the same manner they've reserved a `_t` suffix

Comment: okay, just avoid this naming or there _could_ be collisions. Or always code in german.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- it's reserved because POSIX [says it is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) (search for si_).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @baummitaugen! I'm sorry for not marking yours as the answer for my question, do not take it personal. I just found the answer by @barmar more self-explanatory for future visitors (but, once again, thank you very much for the help).

Comment: @SRG No worries; your vote, your judgement, that's by design.